# phpMyAdmin is displaying code instead of page

Tags: virtualbox, phpmyadmin

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtualbox. I install `apache2.4.18`, `php7.0.8`, `libapache2-mod-php7.0`, `mysql5.7.16` and `phpMyAdmin(4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2)`.

When I type `localhost/phpmyadmin` in the browser (Firefox), I get lots of code instead of the web page for phpMyAdmin. What could be the source of the problem?

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Edit:
phpinfo() is working, but phpMyAdmin is not.

Also I tried typing these commands in the terminal: 
    "a2query -m php7.0"
    "a2enmod php7.0"
They showed that php is enabled.

[image: phpinfo]

Comment: On kubuntu 21.10 - follow same instructions as in question above and answer below, but use php version 8.0 (not 7.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the exact same problem and it was solved for me by doing this:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
sudo a2enconf php7.0-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

How and Why: This happens when PHP7 doesn't configure the default fast-CGI service in the make script. 
`sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif` creates three new mods

1. `/mods-available/proxy.conf`
2. `proxy_fcgi.load`
3. `proxy.load`

Likewise, `sudo a2enconf php7.0-fpm` creates a config file `/conf-available/php7.0-fpm.conf` Once this is done and Apache2 can then run the PHP7 module as a fast-CGI service

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page/42070970#42070970?newreg=8df2fdbc95864157a45228dbc244c47f)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like php is not installed?

Here's the command to install php.

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

If you're still having issues, reconfigure phpmyadmin, and then reload apache.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 reload
```

I typically run `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

This command will install latest packages for apache, php, and other dependencies needed for web apps such as phpmyadmin, wordpres..etc. I highly recommend purging everything and run that command.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to build the lamp server from scratch.

Comment: I have updated my answer with troubleshooting steps.

Comment: I tried "sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin", but it didn't help.

Comment: This worked for me, but I've posted my own answer also because there are a few things worth noting when the installation of the packages using apt is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Is php properly configured? It sounds like it isn't.

Try creating a php file with the following content, and see if it renders:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: phpinfo() is working, but phpMyAdmin is not.

Comment: Also I tried typing these commands in the terminal: "a2query -m php7.0", and "a2enmod php7.0" in the terminal. They showed that php is enabled.

Comment: @Matias These two comments are helpful and they should also be added to your question. To edit your question click this link: http://askubuntu.com/posts/861493/edit

Comment: @Matias Would you share your apache config files? That could help.

Answer (score 0):

Its clear that php is not installed and hence the apache2 service thinks the code is plain html, which it obviously isn't.

I had the same issue so I just did the following under Debian 11 (Buster):

```
sudo apt install php phpmyadmin
```

This then moves the correct php module into the apache2 server mods-enabled directory if apache2 is already installed.

A simple restart of the server worked, using:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

or the older out of date technique:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

One caveat... be very careful not to install php-7.4 under Debian 11 or the most recent Ubuntu package, as this will not upgrade correctly when performing:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo dist-upgrade
```